# How to debug eclipse backend code?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on eclipse JUNO which has been customized by the company I work for.When i click on a particular menu,it's not working the way it should.So i wanted to go through the code which is responsible for that or may be which plugin gets called when I click it.How can i do it?

Comment: Ask the dev team who customized the Eclipse for the source code although it would take a lot of time. What changes have your team made ? Is it a re-compiled version ? Or just a bunch of plugins have been re-compiled ?

Comment: @SaifAsif i have the sourcecode for everything i.e for all plugins.Also the compiled binaries of all plugins.I just want to trace the flow of calls so that i can check the code according to that.Is it possible?

Comment: Run the faulty plugin in debug mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Run your customized eclipse from your development environment in debug mode
2. Attach to running customized eclipse using Eclipse remote debugger

Both options require to have configured development environment in Eclipse, I prefer to use option (2) because it doesn't require to have everything compiled and you always can add missing sources into development environment being in debugging session.

(1) You need to have all sources imported in dev eclipse and compiled without errors. Then you just create Eclipse Application launch configuration and run it in debug mode.

(2) Yo need to start your customized eclipse with remote debugger enabled.
Add in your custom eclipse eclipse.ini file following lines in -vmargs part

```
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=y
```

So you would have something like this

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110505
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=y
```

Now you can start custom eclipse. You won't see anything because it would be in debug mode and wait until remote debugger is attached.  Console output should contain message

```
...
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8001
```

In your development eclipse import source code you want to debug. Make sure you use source code the custom eclipse was built from or line numbers won't match in debug. There is no need to have source compiled without errors.

Go in Project->Debug Configurations ... and create new Remote Java Application config.

Give it name you want and configure port as 8001 (see options in eclipse.ini above).

Go to Source tab and add all projects with sources you need during debug.

Run it, ignore warning about compilation errors and you should see eclipse splash form your custom eclipse started before. After that you can use debugger as usual.